# cwac-merge: is this possible with MergeAdapter?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to solve the following problem, and I'm wondering if the `MergeAdapter` can solve it for me.

I have a `ListView` displaying rows of chats, 1 list item per chat subject. Within a given  row I also want to display the list of users that are participating in the chat. I want a single list row to look like the following:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| This is a subject              Sep 2 |
| user1, user2, user3                  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

The list of chats is in a database table, but the list of users associated with a given chat are in a separate database table (normalized schema).

Here's a simplified schema that I'm using:

```
chats        chatUsers    users
-----        ---------    -----
chatId ----> chatId       name
date         userId ----> userId
subject
```

Would the `MergeAdapter` allow me to visually combine the results of the two queries into a single list item view, where:

**Query 1:** returns the list of chats in time order

**Query 2:** returns the list of users that are part of each chat

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the `MergeAdapter` purpose. It is just an adapter, really. I think your problem here lies on how you are going to retrieve the data and combine them (if I'm getting it right). Personally, by reading your description, I'd suggest you extend your own Loader that combines the data from multiple sources into a data model of your own, ready to be fed into an adapter. Or, if I'm not getting right, combine the results of two loaders into two adapters stitched into the `MergeAdapter`. Again, not sure what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `MergeAdapter` handles `Adapter` *concatentation*, taking adapters representing smaller queries and appending them to behave as if they were one large contiguous adapter.

Comment: In other words, the data in these sub-queries is homogeneous?

Comment: @unluddite: They are not "sub-queries" in the first place. They are adapters.